# SQL find children that have multiple parent records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where we have inserted duplicated data into some tables.

Given the following database schema, I want to find all records with s_id and co_id combinations associated to more than 1 record from table A.  The highlighted rows are the rows I'm looking for, based off of finding the duplicates I need to find the id's from table A associated to the duplicate records.

I'm able to group by s_id & co_id to determine potential duplicates, but because Table B is a 1:M, this isn't entirely accurate.

```
Select c.s_id, c.co_id, Count(*)
from c 
    INNER JOIN b on c.b_id = b.id
    INNER JOIN a on a.id = b.a_id
Group By c.s_id, c.co_id
Having count(*) > 1;
```

[image: ERD]
[image]

Comment: Is c_id = 5 supposed to be joined to a_id = b_id = 4? Why not the row below?

Comment: Yes it is, that's how its setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `count(distinct)`:

```
Select c.s_id, c.co_id, Count(distinct a.id)
from c join
     b
     on c.b_id = b.id join
     a 
     on a.id = b.a_id
Group By c.s_id, c.co_id
having count(distinct a.id) > 1;
```

Comment: I like the answer but from the data, it looks like he's trying to pull more than one record from a given a.id. Further, it doesn't look like the join is valid since there cases shown in the data where a.id <> b.id <> c.id

Comment: I had thought MySQL wouln't allow the DISTINCT in that scenario, but it looks like that's what I'm after.

Comment: @JaredKnipp . . . MySQL definitely supports `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer will get you the `s_id` and `co_id` values. If you need to trace those back to `a` then try this:

```
select distinct a.id
from
    a inner join b on b.a_id = a.id inner join c on c.b_id = b.id inner join
    (
        select c.s_id, c.co_id
        from a inner join b on b.a_id = a.id inner join c on c.b_id = b.id
        group by c.s_id, c.co_id
        having count(distinct a.id) > 1
    ) as dups
        on dups.s_id = c.s_id and dups.co_id = s.co_id
```